# How to set DialogFragment size in Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, size, android-dialogfragment

I'am trying to set size of custom DialogFragment. I was trying something like this:

```
class ChannelEdit : DialogFragment
{
    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.ChannelEdit, container, false);
        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        this.Dialog.Window.WindowManager.DefaultDisplay.GetMetrics(dm);
        int width = dm.WidthPixels;
        int height = dm.HeightPixels;
        this.Dialog.Window.SetLayout((int)width / 2, (int)height / 2);   
        return view;
    }
}
```

But Its not working. I'am not receiving any errors. Could You help me with this?

Comment: Yes., both are set.

Comment: Try to set **wrap_content** to **android:layout_width** and **android:layout_height**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set Layout parameters for root element :

```
int width = this.Resources.DisplayMetrics.WidthPixels;
int height = this.Resources.DisplayMetrics.HeightPixels
rootLayout.setLayoutParams (new LinearLayout.LayoutParams (width, height));
```

Comment: For root element there still was a problem, but i have created second layout in root element, and then works fine :). Thanks!

Comment: Solution should be for xamarin and you have given java code

Comment: What is rootLayout? Also does this code go into OnResume() ?

Comment: rootLayout should be the first (root) layout of your .axml file.
For example in your OnCreateView you could use this line, if your first layout is a linear layout and the id is _myRootLayout_

`var rootLayout = view.FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.myRootLayout)`

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the value in the OnResume (which is unintuative, but works well). I also have code which respects the density, allowing you to strictly control the size, regardless of the density.

```
    public override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();

        var window = Dialog.Window;
        var requestedWidth = (int)(350 * (this.Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density));
        var requestedHeight = (int)(175 * (this.Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density));

        window.SetLayout(requestedWidth, requestedHeight);
        window.SetGravity(GravityFlags.Center);           
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    public override void OnActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        this.Dialog.Window.RequestFeature(WindowFeatures.NoTitle);
        this.Dialog.Window.SetGravity(GravityFlags.Center);
        base.OnActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        int Width = (Resources.DisplayMetrics.WidthPixels) - 150;
        int Height = (Resources.DisplayMetrics.HeightPixels) - 70;
        this.Dialog.Window.Attributes.Width = Width;
        this.Dialog.Window.Attributes.Height = Height;
    }
```

Comment: Do not only add coe. add an Explanation what you have done and why